# What is this please :)?

Tags: part-identification

My friends mini motor got stolen then the next morning I found this part outside my house. I was wondering what it was as I don't know if it was part of it. [image]

Comment: This looks like a throttle plate of a motor bike

Comment: Do they give the engine back piecewise?

Comment: I cannot tell you if this was part of the scooter, but it does fit to the carburetor, as the lever looks to control a choke. The annotation on the edge of the circular part has an arrow and says, "Open". Without more context, it would be *very* hard to know what this belongs to.

Comment: @paulster2 it does say open on the side of it yeah

Comment: I had a piece identical  to this on my motorized bicycle. I don't know its particular function but I used it to start and shut the bike as my kill switch button was broken. And like paulster said it is attached to the carb

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an engine shut-off valve. (Fuel valve or petcock etc.)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petcock